# How do I use scalar operation on same column?

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I'm having trouble understanding how to properly write a query which returns how long VM has been running based on Azure Activity Logs. 
Query below returns latest values when VM was started and when it was deallocated. So I need to return value which tells me how long machine has been running or negative value for situation when VM was deallocated. How do I do that properly?

```
AzureActivity | where TimeGenerated >= ago(30d) and OperationName == "Deallocate Virtual Machine" or OperationName == "Start Virtual Machine" and ActivityStatus == "Succeeded" 
| summarize arg_max(EventSubmissionTimestamp, *) by OperationName
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a table AzureActivity with columns OperationName, TimeGenerated, EventSubmissionTimestamp, MachineId, ActivityStatus (I am deriving columns from your question), you can use next query:

```
// Inline data for the purpose of the query demonstration
let AzureActivity = datatable(OperationName:string, TimeGenerated:datetime, EventSubmissionTimestamp:datetime, MachineId:string, ActivityStatus:string)
[
    // Machine 1
    'Start Virtual Machine', datetime(2019-01-27 00:00), datetime(2019-01-27 00:00), 'Machine1', 'Succeeded',
    'Deallocate Virtual Machine', datetime(2019-01-27 00:00), datetime(2019-01-27 01:00), 'Machine1', 'Succeeded',
    // Machine 2
    'Start Virtual Machine', datetime(2019-01-27 00:00), datetime(2019-01-27 00:00), 'Machine2', 'Succeeded',
];
// Query starts here
let _data = materialize(
    AzureActivity
    | where TimeGenerated >= ago(30d) 
            and (OperationName == "Deallocate Virtual Machine" or OperationName == "Start Virtual Machine") 
            and ActivityStatus == "Succeeded" 
    | summarize arg_max(EventSubmissionTimestamp, *) by OperationName, MachineId
);
let startEvents = _data | where OperationName == 'Start Virtual Machine' | project StartTime = EventSubmissionTimestamp, MachineId;
let deallocateEvents =  _data | where OperationName == 'Deallocate Virtual Machine' | project DeallocateTime = EventSubmissionTimestamp, MachineId;
startEvents | join kind = fullouter (deallocateEvents) on MachineId
| project MachineId, StartTime, DeallocateTime, 
          UpTime=iif(isnotnull(DeallocateTime), 
                        (DeallocateTime-now()),
                        (now()-StartTime))
```